# Xcode 12.1 Debugging EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: xcode, ios14, xcode12

After updating the App to XCode 12 and iOS 14. I get a frequent crash where it does not show the Application line. Below I've given the backtrace I printed from XCode. Rarely I see the crash line stops at executeFetchRequest. I am not sure if this is related to this. How do I debug this issue and stop the crash happening.

Using Xcode 12.1

Device iPhone XS and iPad Air 2.

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #12, queue = 'NSManagedObjectContext 0x28185a2f0', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x2dafa5100)
* frame #0: 0x00000001ba152534 libobjc.A.dylib`object_getIndexedIvars + 28

frame #1: 0x00000001ac0f67a8 CoreData`_PFObjectIDFastHash64 + 36
frame #2: 0x00000001a608e4f8 CoreFoundation`__CFBasicHashRehash + 992
frame #3: 0x00000001a6092414 CoreFoundation`CFBasicHashRemoveValue + 2384
frame #4: 0x00000001a5fa9ec0 CoreFoundation`CFDictionaryRemoveValue + 236
frame #5: 0x00000001ac0431c0 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _forgetObject:propagateToObjectStore:removeFromRegistry:] + 124
frame #6: 0x00000001ac0226ec CoreData`-[_PFManagedObjectReferenceQueue _processReferenceQueue:] + 860
frame #7: 0x00000001ac140198 CoreData`__90-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _registerAsyncReferenceCallback]_block_invoke + 72
frame #8: 0x00000001ac136410 CoreData`developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 164
frame #9: 0x00000001016a15f0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 20
frame #10: 0x00000001016a8fa8 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 736
frame #11: 0x00000001016a9cb4 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_lane_invoke + 448
frame #12: 0x00000001016b5e38 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 1520
frame #13: 0x00000001edf53908 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 276
```

Comment: Does this happen in every Swift 5.x version?

Comment: @Kamil.S I am using Objective-C language. So I am not sure.